# How to draw a filled square box in Java that is exactly in the center of an applet window?

Tags: java, swing

How do you draw a filled square box in Java that is exactly in the center of an applet window? and when resizing the window, it is centered horizontally and vertically within the applet window? I want it to adapt to the vertical height of the screen but stay square even as the horizontal width edges. If the window is resized to be too narrow, then the sides might cut off?

Comment: Are you looking at writing the paint code yourself, or are you looking for a layout manager to keep a component centered?  Also, what do you mean by "stays square even as the horizontal width edges"?  Are you saying you want it to stay a minimum size?

Comment: yes this is the final part of my assignment which I have been riding on for a couple of days before I decide that I have to throw in the towel. this is a paint code itself in which I have been using fillRect to compose. but the problem is when i tried to center it e.g. 
fillRect (width * 5 / 10, height * 5 / 10, width / 10 / 2, height / 10 / 2);
it centers it but only the top left(x,y cords) centers it and the not middle of the the image. sorry, i meant stays square even as the horizontal width changes-> like if it's resized to a very narrow rectangle, it would then be cropped to rectangle

Comment: Can you post your code? Then we could help you with specifics.

Comment: You can edit your submission - use the edit button to do so - and if you could talk about the painting code in a little more detail (as @Kylar mentions) we will be more likely to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a panel that will either make a 30px square in the middle, or resize with the panel. Perhaps it can give you enough to make progress.

```
  private class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    int height = 30;//30 pixels high.
    int width = 30;//30 pixels wide.
    boolean resize = true;


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      int verticalCenter = this.getHeight()/2;
      int horizontalCenter = this.getWidth()/2;

      if(!resize){
        int topLeftSquareCornerY = verticalCenter - (height/2);
        int topLeftSquareCornerX = horizontalCenter - (width/2);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(topLeftSquareCornerX, topLeftSquareCornerY, width, height);
      }else{
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect(15,15,(this.getWidth()-30), this.getHeight()-30);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help... i got it partially figured out because I found a mis-calculations in my code. But thanks for the help. you guys hv been utmost helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your basic problem is figuring out how to place a given rectangle correctly.  You need to have the *middle* of the screen in the *middle* of the rectangle.

The distance from the middle of the rectangle to its sides are half the height and length respectively.

So x1, x2 = middle_x ± width/2, and y1, y2 = middle_y ± height/2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to draw a square with a fixed `size` that stays in the `center` of the panel as the panel is resized. One approach to such problems is start from the end and work backward. You know about `fillRect()`, so write down what you need to "fill on the blanks" required by that method. Call the `center` coordinates `x` and `y`. The top corner would be half of `size` up, and the left corner would be half of `size` to the left; the square's width and height would be just `size`:

```
g.fillRect(left,       top,        width, height);
g.fillRect(x - size/2, y - size/2, size,  size);
```

Now go back and figure out that `x` and `y` are half the panel's width and height, respectively:

```
int x = getWidth() / 2;
int y = getHeight() / 2;
```

Now put it all together in your `paintComponent()` method.